# Best approach for GPGPU/CUDA/OpenCL in Java?

Tags: java, cuda, gpgpu, opencl

General-purpose computing on graphics processing units ([GPGPU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPGPU)) is a very attractive concept to harness the power of the GPU for any kind of computing.

I'd love to use GPGPU for image processing, particles, and fast geometric operations.

Right now, it seems the two contenders in this space are CUDA and OpenCL. I'd like to know:

- Is OpenCL usable yet from Java on Windows/Mac?
- What are the libraries ways to interface to OpenCL/CUDA?
- Is using JNA directly an option?
- Am I forgetting something?

Any real-world experience/examples/war stories are appreciated.

Comment: I would imagine programming GPU in Java would be hard, considering how much I use pointers in cuda programming.  I do not know if there would been much benefit to using Java in device programming, since you are unlikely to have full Java features/libraries implemented which differentiate Java from C++

Comment: I've seen some impressive Java demos that used GLSL and probably CUDA, so it is certainly possible.

Comment: Did you check jcuda.org and jocl.org?

Comment: I know about them, however I can't judge the quality. Have you any experience with them?

Comment: These links may interest you: http://www.pixelnerve.com/v/2009/10/30/opencl-4-java/ - http://www.prace-project.eu/documents/05_cudaopencl_hh.pdf

Comment: I have no experience with it myself, but it seems to me that http://code.google.com/p/javacl/ is far more Java-ish than jcuda / jocl.

Comment: I'm not not sure if Java is the right language if you want performance..

Comment: @Nils: and so it's why he wants to push all the number crunching on the GPU... Anyway, even plain C or x86 asm would have a hard task for competing against massive data parallel processors like GPUs.

Comment: If he can shift most of the processing to the gpu and keep work done on CPU at minimum it wont matter much what language he uses.

Comment: Have a look, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014327/gpu-programming-cuda-or-opencl

Answer (score 64, accepted):

AFAIK, [JavaCL / OpenCL4Java](https://github.com/nativelibs4java/JavaCL) is the only OpenCL binding that is available on all platforms right now (including MacOS X, FreeBSD, Linux, Windows, Solaris, all in Intel 32, 64 bits and ppc variants, thanks to its use of [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/)).

It has demos that actually run fine from Java Web Start at least on Mac and Windows (to avoid random crashes on Linux, please see [this wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/javacl/wiki/TroubleShootingJavaCLOnLinux), such as this [Particles Demo](http://nativelibs4java.sourceforge.net/webstart/OpenCL/ParticlesDemo.jnlp).

It also comes with a few utilities (GPGPU random number generation, basic parallel reduction, linear algebra) and a [Scala DSL](http://ochafik.free.fr/blog/?p=207).

Finally, it's the oldest bindings available (since june 2009) and [it has an active user community](http://groups.google.com/group/nativelibs4java).

(Disclaimer: I'm [JavaCL](http://code.google.co)'s author :-))

Comment: Oh I was so excited for the JNLP, but apparently it doesnt like my macbook. So much for cross platform.

Comment: @Karl Oh sorry, I broke the JNLP (the JAR recently changed names) ! That's now fixed, hope you'll try again... (and cross-platform-wise : it was broken consistently on all platforms ;-))

Comment: The recent tightening in Java 7 security cause the Particle Demo Web Start to fail with an exception.

Comment: @zOlive The last JavaCl link to google code is not available anymore.

Answer (score 35):

You may also consider [Aparapi](http://github.com/aparapi/aparapi).  It allows you to write your code in Java and will attempt to convert bytecode to OpenCL at runtime.

Full disclosure.  I am the Aparapi developer.

Comment: Is aparapi still maintained?

Comment: @MrJedi: I think so, latest commit on github is only some days old: https://github.com/aparapi/aparapi

Comment: It is "somewhat maintained";) I am a maintainer.

Answer (score 12):

Well CUDA is a modification of C, to write CUDA kernel you have to code in C, and then compile to executable form with nvidia's CUDA compiler. Produced native code could then be linked with Java using JNI. So technically you can't write kernel code from Java. There is JCUDA http://www.jcuda.de/jcuda/JCuda.html, it provides you with cuda's apis for general memory/device menagement and some Java methods that are implemented in CUDA and JNI wrapped (FFT, some linear algebra methods.. etc etc..).

On the other hand OpenCL is just an API. OpenCL kernels are plain strings passed to the API so using OpenCL from Java you should be able to specify your own kernels. OpenCL binding for java can be found here http://www.jocl.org/.

Comment: if JNA (http://jna.dev.java.net) is supported on your platform, I would use that to invoke the native code, as it's much less effort than coding a JNI library.

Answer (score 11):

I've been using JOCL and I'm very happy with it.

The main disadvantage of OpenCL over CUDA (at least for me) is the lack of available libraries (Thrust, CUDPP, etc). However CUDA can be easily ported to OpenCL, and by looking at how those libraries work (algorithms, strategies, etc) is actually very nice as you learn a lot with it.

Answer (score 7):

I know it's late but take a look at this: https://github.com/pcpratts/rootbeer1

I have not worked with it but seems much easier to use than other solutions.

From the project page:

Rootbeer is more advanced than CUDA or OpenCL Java Language Bindings. With bindings the developer must serialize complex graphs of objects into arrays of primitive types. With Rootbeer this is done automatically. Also with language bindings, the developer must write the GPU kernel in CUDA or OpenCL. With Rootbeer a static analysis of the Java Bytecode is done (using Soot) and CUDA code is automatically generated.

Answer (score 2):

I can also recommend [JOCL by jogamp.org](http://jogamp.org/jocl/www/), works on Linux, Mac, and Windows. [CONRAD](http://conrad.stanford.edu), for example, uses heavily OpenCL in combination with JOCL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do some image processing or geometric operations, you may want a linear algebra library with gpu support (with CUDA for instance). I would suggest you ND4J witch is the linear algrebra with CUDA GPU support on which DeepLearning4J is built. With that you don't have to deal with CUDA directly and have to low level code in c. Plus if you want to do more stuff with image with DL4J you will have access to specific image processing operations such as convolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the CUDA4J API

http://sett.com/gpgpu/the-cuda4j-api