# Accessing GPU through Java for Salted Hashing

Tags: java, md5, hash, gpu, saltedhash

I'm looking to write a program that can do some salted (MD5) hashing for me. To reduce the impact on my system, and increase the speed, I want to run the calculations through the GPU. So I have a few questions:
1) Does Java have native support for GPU processing?
2) Does Java have native support for salted MD5 hashing?
3) Is anybody aware of an open source program that already does this?
4) Anything else you think might be helpful?
Answers to any or all questions are appreciated, even just links to related documentation.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [Best approach for GPGPU/CUDA/OpenCL in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633483/best-approach-for-gpgpu-cuda-opencl-in-java).  It's only about a year old so information there is probably still relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a blog by someone who has a similar idea to you: http://www.golubev.com/hashgpu.htm

He released a working hash bruteforcer using the GPU which can be found [here](http://www.golubev.com/hashgpu.htm).

Comment: Uh, the link is dead.