# How to make python run using Windows GPU?

Tags: python, gpu

I've been trying to improve the performance of my python scripts and would like to run some using my computer's built-in GPU. However, my computer is Windows 10 and its GPU is not CUDA compatible. From what I've seen, it seems that the GPU must be CUDA compatible in order for it to run python scripts. Is there any way to utilize my GPU for said purposes? If not, are there other programming languages in which I *can* do this?

Comment: What's the make/model of the GPU?

Comment: Intel(R) HD Graphics 620

Comment: There's a framing issue here. GPUs never run Python scripts. Rather, you can write a Python script that interfaces with some lower-level library to perform _some computations_ using the GPU.

Comment: That would be enough. How might I go about doing that?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820064/can-i-run-cuda-or-opencl-on-intel-processor-graphics-i7-3rd-or-4rd-generation for some CUDA alternatives.

Comment: Thanks! OpenCL looks promising. I'll look into it.

Comment: Your GPU is slower than your CPU.  You will not be helping yourself by migrating your processing.  It's a lower-end graphics chip.  It's not clear to me that it even HAS computation units that can be addressed separately.

Answer (score 0):

The GPU is a proccessing unit for graphics. It most likely won't help except for drawing polygons, transfering data, or massive data sets. The closest you can get is importing a module (depending on your needs), that uses C++ to interact with the GPU (such as OpenCL), or coding interactions yourself (much more complicated).

To answer your 2nd question, C++ or C# should work with your GPU.
Please specify what script you are trying to run for more detail
Good luck!

Comment: Anyway, my point is you might just need to optimize your code. There a few cases where the GPU is the main issue in performance. I would also recommend Numba for data.